# Programmatically attaching a tool tip to dojo datagrid after validating a cell content rather than a popup

Tags: dojo

I was trying to validate a cell using the following code snippet

```
` dojo.addOnLoad(function(){    
      dojo.connect(grid, "onApplyCellEdit", this, validateName);

});

function validateName(inValue, inRowIndex, inFieldIndex){

    if(inValue){
        if(inFieldIndex=='employeeLastName') {`
```

and i wanted to add a tooltip to the cell rather than showing a dialog box which iam currently doing .I tried using dojo domnode to get the cell but couldnt ,is there any way we can add a tool tip to the edited cell

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that might help.  It grabs the dojo grid object and loops 
though selected (highlighted) cells..Not sure about adding tooltip to each cell though...

```
var gridy = dijit.byId("grid");
var items = gridy.selection.getSelected();
dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem) {
  if (selectedItem !== null) {
    var attribute = gridy.store.getAttributes(selectedItem);
    for (var i = 0; i < attribute.length; i++) {
      var colNm = gridy.getCellName(gridy.getCell(i));
      var value = gridy.store.getValues(selectedItem, colNm);
      var chk_val = String(value);
    }
  }  
});
```